# Array within a NSDictionary: how to save to the NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, sdk

I would like to save `Array/NSDictionary` to `NSUserDefaults` but anything I try is just not working. Here is my code so please if you know how to do this, help me.

```
NSArray *oneArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Radio One",nil];
NSDictionary *one = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:oneArray forKey:@"Stations"];

NSArray *oneLinkArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://mobile.com:28000/",nil];
NSDictionary *oneLink = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:oneLinkArray forKey:@"Stations"];

[data addObject:one];
[link addObject:oneLink];
```

The reason I need this is to put this station into favorites. So my thinking is to save these info in to `NSUserDefaults` and retrieve in favorites table.

Thanks and please any suggestion is welcomed and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this when you store everything into a dictionary

```
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:link forKey:@"dictionary1"];
```

Or you can put everything into an array and store it like this

```
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"array1"];
```

You can access it again by using

```
    NSDictionary * myDictionary = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"dictionary1"];
```

Comment: If the above still does not work then can you see the log for data and link

Comment: Everything is already in a dictionary. What I'm trying to do is to take this existing array and put into NSUserDefaults. Thanks for your suggestion I'll try but if you have any other suggestion, please share. Thanks

Comment: I have around 50 stations in array. So, my idea is to make when user click on "star" in detailview that will trigger action to transfer data from array to NSUserDefaults. I think this is the way to do it but if someone has done something similar or the same please share. Thanks

Comment: The problem isn't that you're saving an NSArray, it's what's inside the array. Objects stored to user defaults must be plist types only: data, number, string, dictionary or array

Comment: I endup doing what Jai suggested and it is working. Her is my code:         


NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryToAdd = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[dictionaryToAdd setObject:theHeaderText forKey:@"data"];

[dictionaryToAdd setObject:theLabelText forKey:@"one"]

[dictionaryToAdd setObject:linkText forKey:@"link"];

NSUserDefaults *myDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[myDefaults setObject:dictionaryToAdd forKey:@"Stations"];
        
[myDefaults synchronize];

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Typically adding an object into NSUserDefaults goes like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryToAdd = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dictionaryToAdd setObject:@"xyz" forKey:@"myKey"];

NSUserDefaults *myDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[myDefaults setObject:dictionaryToAdd forKey:@"someKey"];

[myDefaults synchronize];
```

A few things on your code above though - you're adding stuff into 'data' and 'link' but I don't see those in your code, so I'm assuming those arrays exist somewhere.

To sum it up - declare an NSUserDefaults object, set objects into it like an NSDictionary, and then synchronize it to save data.

Additional code as requested:

```
//You have an array named arrayToAdd that has already been created
NSUserDefaults *myDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[myDefaults setObject:arrayToAdd forKey:@"SomeKeyThatYouMakeUp"];
[myDefaults synchronize];

//You want to get the array out of NSUserDefaults
NSArray *mySavedArray;
NSUserDefaults *myDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
mySavedArray = [myDefaults objectForKey:@"SomeKeyThatYouMakeUp"];
```

Comment: You are right the code above is code how I add 'data' and 'link' to arrays. So now based on that how can i add those arrays to NSUserDefaults. (I did not start I did not post any code because I do not know how) Thanks,

Comment: I added another block of code to my response above to demonstrate this. It's pretty much the same as adding an NSMutableDictionary as per first example. Actually, it's pretty much the same as adding any object at all (note: it has to be an object) to an NSDictionary. Let me know if I can be of further help.

Comment: I endup doing what Jai suggested and it is working. Her is my code:         


NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryToAdd = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[dictionaryToAdd setObject:theHeaderText forKey:@"data"];

[dictionaryToAdd setObject:theLabelText forKey:@"one"]

[dictionaryToAdd setObject:linkText forKey:@"link"];

NSUserDefaults *myDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[myDefaults setObject:dictionaryToAdd forKey:@"Stations"];
        
[myDefaults synchronize];

THANKS